# Azure Function: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: System.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderDescriptor

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I am using Service Bus Topic trigger azure function, and I am getting below exception when registering JanrainApiClient singleton in Startup.cs class.

> An item with the same key has already been added. Key:
> System.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderDescriptor, StackTrace:   at
> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue
> value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
>
> This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties
> can only be modified before sending the first request., StackTrace:
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.CheckDisposedOrStarted()
> [2022-08-19T14:36:29.077Z]    at
> System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.GetOrCreateHeaderInfo(HeaderDescriptor
> descriptor, Boolean parseRawValues) [2022-08-19T14:36:29.078Z]    at
> System.Net.Http.HttpClient.set_BaseAddress(Uri value)
> [2022-08-19T14:36:29.079Z]    at
> System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.SetParsedValue(HeaderDescriptor
> descriptor, Object value) [2022-08-19T14:36:29.081Z]    at
> System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpRequestHeaders.set_Authorization(AuthenticationHeaderValue
> value)

Below is my `JanrainApiClient` class

```
public class JanrainApiClient : IJanrainApiClient
    {
       
        private readonly ILogger<JanrainApiClient> logger;
        private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
        private readonly JanrainConfigOption janrainConfigOption;

            public JanrainApiClient(ILogger<JanrainApiClient> logger,
            IOptions<JanrainConfigOption> janrainConfigOption,
            IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
            this.janrainConfigOption = janrainConfigOption.Value;
            this.httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        }

      
        public async Task<JanrainResultDto> FindAsync(string userUUID)
        {
            try
            {
                logger.LogInformation("{class} - {method} - Start",
                  nameof(JanrainApiClient), nameof(JanrainApiClient.FindAsync));

                JanrainResultDto resultDto = new JanrainResultDto();

                var request = GetJanrainApiRequest(userUUID);

                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(GetServiceUrl(request));

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(janrainConfigOption.Scheme, janrainConfigOption.ApiAuth);

                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(GetServiceUrl(request));

                var jsonAsString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                JanrainApiResponse entityFindResponse = jsonAsString.AsPoco<JanrainApiResponse>();

                if (entityFindResponse != null && entityFindResponse.Results != null)
                {
                    resultDto = entityFindResponse.Results.FirstOrDefault();
                }
                else
                {
                    logger.LogError($"Error while requesting Janrain info for UserUUId:{userUUID}." +
                        $"Error:{entityFindResponse?.Error}, ErrorMessage:{entityFindResponse?.ErrorDescription}");
                }

                logger.LogInformation("{class} - {method} - End",
                 nameof(JanrainApiClient), nameof(JanrainApiClient.FindAsync));

                return resultDto;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError($"Exception while calling Janrain entity Find API for UserUUId :{userUUID}, " +
                    $"Error message:{ex.Message}, StackTrace:{ex.StackTrace}");
                throw;
            }
        }
                     
        private JanrainApiRequest GetJanrainApiRequest(string userUUId)
        {
            return new JanrainApiRequest
            {
                Username = string.Empty,
                TypeName = janrainConfigOption.TypeName,
                Attributes = JanrainResultDto.Attributes(),
                QueryFilter = $"uuid='{userUUId}'",
                ClientId = janrainConfigOption.ClientId,
            };
        }

        private string GetServiceUrl(JanrainApiRequest request)
        {
            return $"{janrainConfigOption.EntityFindApiUrl}{request.ToQueryString()}";
        }
       

    }
```

Below is my `Startup.cs` class

```
 public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddLogging();
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IJanrainApiClient, JanrainApiClient>();
        }
    }
```

Am i missing anything here?

Comment: Can you check if you have to add headers to default request headers.  Often the framework sets it via attributes or other configuration.  The request it only allowed to have one instance of some headers, that's what the execption is about.  Most likely you set the header manually and it is added by the framework.

Comment: Yes! I am adding two headers(application/json and Authorize) in JanrainApiClient, as shown in the question body.  Is this creating issue? If yes! then could you please suggest how should I modify this?